# ActiveMQ 5.1.1 WebSphere 8.5.5 Activation Spec configuration?

Tags: java, websphere, activemq-classic

Thanks to Maarten I was able to get basic ActiveMQ JMS topics and connection factories working in WAS.  He has a nice write up in his reply to this topic:  [ActiveMQ 5.11 with WebSphere Application Server 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099231/activemq-5-11-with-websphere-application-server-8-5)

But I cannot find a way to define any ActiveMQ JMS Activation Specs in the WAS admin console.  And of course I need those in order to trigger my MDBs.  ActiveMQ simply doesn't show up as a JMS provider when creating a new AS.

How do I configure Activation Specs in WAS using ActiveMQ as the provider?  Am I missing a jar file?

activemq-client-5.11.0.jar
hawtbuf-1.11.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar

Comment: Maybe interesting (or not): Another option to trigger MDB's in WAS is listener ports. Just need to specify the QCF and Queue in the WAS console and map the listener port to the MDB in your application configuration.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I'll look into that approach too.

Comment: Try the other way around. Fist go your `Resources > JMS > JMS Providers >  JMS Generic provider`, that you configured for ActiveMQ, then you should have in `Additional Properties` section `Activation Specifications`. Listener ports are already deprecated, so I wouldn't go that way.

Comment: Gas - Unfortunately, there is no Activation Specification listed under the Additional Properties for the ActiveMQ JMS Provider.  It is there for the default messaging bus and MQ.

Comment: From the WAS App Server Messaging Handbook: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247770.pdf

When messages are received using a JMS provider implemented with a JCA 1.5 resource adapter, such as the default messaging provider or the WebSphere MQ messaging provider, the message-driven beans use a J2C activation specification to listen for incoming messages.

If the JMS provider does not have a JCA 1.5 resource adapter (for example, the V5 default messaging provider), you must configure JMS message-driven beans against a listener port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Activation specification, you need to install ActiveMQ as JCA 1.5 compliant resource adapter. As far as I know, ActiveMQ provides resource adapter as separate install.

See also:

- [Deploying the ActiveMQ Resource Adapter into IBM WebSphere](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/video/thumbnails/WAS-AMQ-RAR-Instructions.pdf)
- [Managing messaging with a third-party JCA 1.5 or 1.6-compliant messaging provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tmp_ep_ra.html?lang=en)
- [ActiveMQ resource adapter](http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter.html)

Listener ports are stabilized, and should only be used if provider doesn't support JCA.

Answer (score 0):

Really straight forward once you understand (of course).
From the IBM Redbook mentioned above, sg247770.pdf, we need to configure ActiveMQ as a Generic JMS provider in WAS.  And since we want to use Activation Specs, again from the Redbook, we need to use the ActiveMQ Resource Adapter, or rar file.  There is a link on the ActiveMQ page to the latest rar, I don't need to provide it here.  Once the rar is installed, using the WAS Console/Resources/Resource Adapters menu, you can configure J2C CFs, ASs, and administered objects including Queues and Topics from the rar configuration page.  These will all have custom properties where you will enter your destinations, etc.