# IBM Websphere and JMS/Active MQ integration

Tags: websphere, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I would like to publish a message to Active MQ using JMS or spring-jms from an application hosted inside IBM Websphere.  Question is can I do that using JMS API or using spring-jms by adding the required libraries to the classpath ? or I have to configure JNDI lookup and other configurations in the WAS console ?  If you can point me to any documentation that would be great.

Comment: Check this, it more or less outlines all steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099231/activemq-5-11-with-websphere-application-server-8-5

Comment: The above link requires configuring in WAS console.  If you use spring jms do we have to configure connection factory in the console or can be do that programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly simply create your own connection factories, etc. programatically.  You would still have access to the transaction manager and other container resources.

As already pointed out, deployment of the resource adapter is the preferred mechanism.  This allows the JEE container to manage connection pools and provide JMS resources as container managed resources.

Please be aware that the ActiveMQ resource adapter deploys a number of Spring artifacts.  Under the JEE specification, any classes that are deployed by a JCA adapter are on the classpath for all deployments.  This can be very problematic.

Comment: I forgot to mention.... was bugging me all day yesterday ....  In the JEE specification, you can only have one JMS sessions per JMS connection if the connection factory is managed via a JCA.  If you create your own unmanaged connection factory programatically, you can still have multiple sessions per connection.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way to do this is create a [**Resource Adapter**](https://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter) (*WAS Console*: Resources>Resource Adapters>Install RAR), that is install the AMQ provided RAR file (the [5.16.* RAR versions](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar/5.16.6/overview) I think are the ones supporting Java 8 that is supported by current tWAS versions). Add all the relevant AMQ Config as Resource Adapter *Custom Properties(serverURL, credentials etc)*.

Then you have to create all relevant JMS Resources as **J2C Objects**, i.e. **J2C Connection Factories**, **J2C Administered Objects(Topics, Queues)**, defining also a JNDI Name to call them.